# How to write Unit Test for time sensitive constant

Tags: c#, unit-testing

This might be an obvious answer to this but I can't figure out how best to create a unit test for the following:

```
Assert.AreEqual(27, AgeCalculator.GetAge(new DateTime(1983, 10, 6))); // this test will fail tomorrow
Assert.AreEqual(26, AgeCalculator.GetAge(new DateTime(1984, 11, 14)));
Assert.AreEqual(9, AgeCalculator.GetAge(new DateTime(2002, 05, 7)));
Assert.AreEqual(7, AgeCalculator.GetAge(new DateTime(2003, 11, 03)));
Assert.AreEqual(4, AgeCalculator.GetAge(new DateTime(2007, 05, 10)));
```

I've created a GetAge() method that I want a test to ensure any future changes to that method are OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [following blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2007/05/12/testingagainstthecurrenttime.aspx) which is part of a nice [series of posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2007/05/11/testingagainstnondeterminism.aspx) for testing against non-determinism.

Comment: Thanks the link - that's a great series. Non-deterministic was the word I was looking for too but didn't click when posting the question :) Thanks again

Comment: It's sometimes easy to forget that when you ask for the current time you are creating an implicit dependency on your system clock. Wrapping those calls in your own time provider, as this post does, will immediately improve the robustness of your unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

I would mock the datetime object inside of your `AgeCalculator` so that it always uses the same testing date.